# How do i link SQLite Database into an Android Application ? and Via Application which methods will be used to retrieve the database records?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am not been able to link SQLite database with my application.
The size of database is around 4-5 Mb.
Give me an answer that will help me to link database and methods of making an QUERY to the database and retrieve the same.
Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Your existing database should be located in your assets folder. Open the database:

```
InputStream copy = context.getAssets().open(LOCAL_DB_NAME);
```

Copy the database to the location "`data/data/<package_name>/databases`":

```
//where DB_PATH is the above....
String path_DB = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
OutputStream dbOut = new FileOutputStream(path_DB);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = copy.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    dbOut.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

// Close the streams
dbOut.flush();
dbOut.close();
copy.close();
```

After that create custom SQLIteOpenHelper class, which extends [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) and acquire instance of your database. You can open the copied database with something like:

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path_DB, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

or

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path_DB, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

For examples on how to execute queries towards the database, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#sqliteoverview_sqliteopenhelper).